# How to change from KDE to Gnome or suggest solution

Tags: gnome, kde, power-management, battery

I was using Ubuntu 21.04 and it managed my battery very well ( I have battery with 17% health {no I will not change it! there is no original asus battery in my region !}) but recently switched to Kubuntu 22.04 for refreshness and fun.

Here is my problem:
In Ubuntu 21.04, my battery manages to hold for 2~4 hours but now with Kubuntu 22.04 it can't hold more than 30 minutes!

So how to install gnome with out losing plasma lovely apps and features?

Or what can I do about power management?

Comment: @guiverc thanks for pointing that i forgot to mention kubuntu is 22.04.

Comment: If you prefer Gnome, install normal Ubuntu. Ubuntu=Gnome, Kubuntu=KDE

Comment: A dead battery will not improve. Even restoring 21.04 you will have 1/2 an hour. " no original asus battery in my region" Then get an unofficial one or a new system. And DHL/.GPS/FEDEX and the likes do not deliver where you are?  No amount of software will fix any amount of broken hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command in your terminal

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Comment: can you please edit your answer to include a short description of what this command does and why it solves the OP's question. Thanks